# drush puts my website in a subdirectory named 'web'

Tags: drush, 9, installation

I use shared web hosting with Cpanel, LAMP and Composer.

I have installed Drupal with Drush on a registered web domain (example.com).

My website is accessible via `example.com/web/` but I would expect the website to be accessible via `example.com` only. Why is that the case and how to handle that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to fix this

You need to set the web root for the domain (to `web`).  You need to do this on your web server, not in Drupal.  If you're on a shared host, something like CPanel will have a setting for the web root.

### Why does Drush install Drupal in the web subdirectory?

Drupal has a lot of support files, **many of which should never be exposed to the public by your webserver**.  So, the files that should be exposed get put in the `web` directory, while the other utility files get put in other directories.